# How can I create table of contents in word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

**How can I generate a table of contents which has links to the paragraphs?**

I know how to create a auto-generated table of contents:

1. Apply the **Heading 1** style to that paragraph.

   - On the **Home** tab, in the **Styles group**, click the **Heading 1** thumbnail.
2. Generate table of contents.

   - Choose **References > Table of Contents** and select one of the stiles

The actual problem is creating one with links to the paragraphs. I remember that in earlier versions of word this was easy to achieve. I would like to avoid manually creating the links in `label` and `ref` style. I have searched for answers but I found them hard to understand and follow. Some easy clear steps would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by links to the paragraphs, or post links to some of the answers you found hard to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default (say, using "Automatic Table 1") they *are* created with hyperlinks.  If you hit "Insert Table Of contents..." (instead of just picking a premade style) it will show you a *Web Preview*:

[image]

The trick is, you just can't *see* them while in the "Print Layout" view, because you usually wouldn't want to print a hyperlink. :)

Switch to another layout like "Reading" or "Web Layout" to make them more accessible and/or visible:

[image]

Having said all that, you can *use* them in the Print Layout, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while clicking them; they just aren't visibly displayed.

Comment: Thank you! The thing that got me confused is that when I pick a premade stile it does not say _Ctrl+Click to follow link_ when keeping the mouse over.